# How can I integrate Bower with Gulp.js?

Tags: bower, gulp

I am trying to write a gulp task that does a few things

1. Install the Bower dependencies
2. Concat those dependencies into one file in the order of the dependencies

I was hoping to do this without having to specify the paths to those dependencies. I know there is the command `bower list --paths` but I am unsure of if it is possible to tie it together.

Any thoughts?

## Edit

So I am trying to use the [gulp-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/gulp-bower-files) and I am getting an eaccess error and its not generating the concatenated file.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var bower_files = require('gulp-bower-files');

gulp.task("libs", function(){
    bower_files()
    .pipe(concat('./libs.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("/"));
});
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "ember-boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.6.0-beta.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.7"
  }
}
```

and I keep coming across this error

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EACCES, open '/libs.js'
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files)

It grabs all production (main) files of your Bower packages defined in your project's bower.json and use them as your gulp src for your task.

integrate it in your gulpfile:

```
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
```

I made this task that grabs all production files, filters css/js/fonts and outputs them in the public folder in their respective subfolders (css/js/fonts).

Here's an example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// define plug-ins
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter'); // 4.0.0+
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

// Define paths variables
var dest_path =  'www';
// grab libraries files from bower_components, minify and push in /public
gulp.task('publish-components', function() {

        var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js');
        var cssFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.css');
        var fontFilter = gulpFilter(['**/*.eot', '**/*.woff', '**/*.svg', '**/*.ttf']);

        return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())

        // grab vendor js files from bower_components, minify and push in /public
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/js/'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/js/'))
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())

        // grab vendor css files from bower_components, minify and push in /public
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/css'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/css'))
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())

        // grab vendor font files from bower_components and push in /public
        .pipe(fontFilter)
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/fonts'));
});
```

Comment: where does gulpFilter come from? How's it defined

Comment: The script I posted uses some variables and gulp-plugins (gulp-filter, gulp-uglify, gulp-flatten, etc.), you have to define them like in my example, here is how: http://jsfiddle.net/pznaw4yq/

Comment: nice solution. but how (and when) to merge vendor scripts/styles files with app's own files ? i tried to do it with `event-stream` and `inject` but with no success.

Comment: Well this is just a simple script i made to briefly explain a solution, if you need more i suggest you to try [YEOMAN](http://yeoman.io) with [THIS](https://github.com/pwnjack/yeoman-gulp-less) generator, it works with gulp and is a nice starting point.

Comment: Hey @zok and cully-mason, guys, did you have solved topic issue? If yes -- share yours gulpfile please.

Comment: Hi milushov, just thought i'd share a complete gulpfile for this sort of thing. http://pastebin.com/j4E9wQxW

I'd compile a seperate task in gulp for your app specific files which calls the task discussed here.

Comment: Just an FYI `gulp-minify-css` has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) in favor of [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css)

Answer (score 10):

I was attempting to run the listed gulpfile and ran into a couple errors. First gulpFilter.restore is not a function, and secondly if you plan on restoring the filtered files you need to pass {restore: true} when you define your filters.
Like so:

```
// gulpfile.js

var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

var gulp = require('gulp');

// define plug-ins
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten'),
  gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

// Define paths variables
var dest_path =  'www';

// grab libraries files from bower_components, minify and push in /public
gulp.task('publish-components', function() {
  var jsFilter = gulpFilter('*.js', {restore: true}),
      cssFilter = gulpFilter('*.css', {restore: true}),
      fontFilter = gulpFilter(['*.eot', '*.woff', '*.svg', '*.ttf'], {restore: true});

  return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())

  // grab vendor js files from bower_components, minify and push in /public
  .pipe(jsFilter)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/js/'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(rename({
    suffix: ".min"
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/js/'))
  .pipe(jsFilter.restore)

  // grab vendor css files from bower_components, minify and push in /public
  .pipe(cssFilter)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/css'))
  .pipe(minifycss())
  .pipe(rename({
      suffix: ".min"
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/css'))
  .pipe(cssFilter.restore)

  // grab vendor font files from bower_components and push in /public
  .pipe(fontFilter)
  .pipe(flatten())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_path + '/fonts'));
});
```

After the changes mentioned it ran perfectly. :)