# Bower dist files copy / symlink or what?

Tags: bower

im new to Bower. I just want to have latest jquery, bootstrap, etc. by using Bower. Unfortionally it is downloading tons of "shit" i dont want, like source files, license, etc...

Anyway, how do I get the file i want: `project/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` into my actual folder `project/js` ?

Is there any way by using Bower? If I copy them by hand, whats the point of using Bower then? Also i dont want to link my vendors to the bower_components-folder.

Answer (score -1):

I think you use Grunt and "grunt-bower":

- http://gruntjs.com/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower

Or Gulp and "gulp-bower":

- http://gulpjs.com/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bower

Here's a somewhat similar question, but from someone who is further along. I think the answer and the JsFiddle are helpful:

- [How can I integrate Bower with Gulp.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901726/how-can-i-integrate-bower-with-gulp-js)