# Automatically add js/css files to ionic projects

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, automation, bower, gulp-inject

I want to **automate the injection of new js/css files to my ionic project**. So, I found [this really useful article](http://digitaldrummerj.me/gulp-inject/), which shows how to do it using **gulp inject**, but just with my own js/css files (**those in js/css folders**).

If I now install another external library using bower, for example:

```
bower install angular-google-maps --save
```

That library is not automatically injected, because **it's installed in lib folder, outside js folder**, as it's a library from an external vendor.

I guess **I should have another gulp task to minimize the external libraries installed with bower, and put them into js folder to make them injectable**. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.
Quoting your article:

> There is all of kinds of additional functionality that you can perform with gulp such as minifying of css and javascript files, running npm/bower commands, or running sass compile commands. The gulp-inject is just one module.

You can use a module like [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) to retrieve these files and do whatever you want with them.
You can also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901726/how-can-i-integrate-bower-with-gulp-js) to get a starting point.